# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog model_checkout_order.php on line 618

Tags: opencart

When finishing the request in Opencart I get the following error.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' vqmod/vqcache/vq2-catalog model_checkout_order.php on line 618
```

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Kindly use english language. So that every one can understand.

Comment: Ok...

When finishing the request in Opencart I get the following error.
Could someone please help me?